# SimpleXML: how to replace node name?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to output xml file as html. It seems like simpleXML processing is faster than XSL on my files (files are 2-3mb each). So I ended with simpleXML. Everything seems fine, files loaded ok with `$data = simplexml_load_string($file)` but now I need to replace node names with html tag names and build a new document with `$data->asXML()`.
Is there any way to do this?

What I have now:

```
    <body>
 <section>
  <title>
   <p>sometext</p>
  </title>
  <epigraph>
    <p>sometext</p>
  </epigraph>
  <stanza>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
  </stanza>
  <stanza>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
    <v>sometext</v>
  </stanza>
   <section>
    <title>
     <p>sometext</p>
    </title>
    <epigraph>
      <p>sometext</p>
    </epigraph>
    <stanza>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
    </stanza>
    <stanza>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
      <v>sometext</v>
    </stanza>
   </section>
 </section>
</body>
```

And I'd like to have this:

```
   <body>
 <div class="section">
  <h2>
   <span>sometext</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="epigraph">
    <p>sometext</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
    <li>sometext</li>
  </ul>
   <div class="section">
    <h2>
     <span>sometext</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="epigraph">
      <p>sometext</p>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
      <li>sometext</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do that directly. You can either

- Parse it and loop over using `foreach` and such,
- Or, if the xml is guaranteed to be that simple and consistent, you can simply do something like
  `strtr($xml, array('stanza>' => 'ul>', 'v>' => 'li>', ...));`